# How to set a sessionStorage in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, session-storage

I need to change the value of one of the parameters in the sessionStorage but I'm not even sure if this is possible through Cypress. Couldn't find any useful information about this in their documentation.

This is the javascript code that I'm trying to run with Cypress without any success:

```
var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("vuex"))
data.country = "DE"
sessionStorage.setItem("vuex", JSON.stringify(data))
```

It works perfectly fine if I execute it in the console but I don't know how to make it work with Cypress.

Even if I write a simple javascript code like

```
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("vuex"))
```

It returns Null with Cypress.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting null for this javascript code and if this operation is even possible with Cypress?

Answer (score 10):

Found the solution:

```
cy.window().then( win => {

    var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("vuex"))
    data.country = "DE"
    sessionStorage.setItem("vuex", JSON.stringify(data))

})
```

Comment: That worked nicely, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example of setting a user in session storage in Cypress

```js
cy.fixture("user.json").then((users) => {
        // Get the user fixture
        let user = user.sessionStorageContent;

        // Stringify the user object
        let userContent = JSON.stringify(user);

        cy.window().then((win) => {
          // Set the user object in the sessionStorage
          win.sessionStorage.setItem("user", userContent);
        });
      });
```